# How to input array of string to quicksort in cuda

Tags: c, cuda, quicksort

I am trying to run this code to quick sort without recursion, it run when I input an array of char, but when I try to input string, it return symbol not string in the output.

So if anyone know what's the error I made in this code, I will appreciate. Because my plan is to read file txt and store the information form file in an array and then input this array in quicksort.

This code is implemented in CUDA.

```
void quick_p(char c[][30], int count)
{
   int partitions[1024];
   int newpartitions[1024];

   partitions[0]=0;
   partitions[1]=count-1;
   int threads=1;

   char *dev_c;
   cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, count * sizeof( char));

   int *dev_p;
   int *dev_pn;
   cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_p , 1024 * sizeof(int));
   cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_pn, 1024 * sizeof(int));

   cudaMemcpy(dev_c, c, count * sizeof( char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   while(true)
   {
        cudaMemcpy(dev_p, partitions , sizeof(partitions), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(dev_pn, newpartitions , sizeof(newpartitions), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        Split<<<1,threads>>>(&dev_c,dev_p,dev_pn,threads);

        // get result back and loop again
        cudaMemcpy(newpartitions,dev_pn, sizeof(partitions), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        int tmp=0;
        for(int i=0;i<threads*2;i++)
        {
            int idx=i*2;
            if (newpartitions[idx]<newpartitions[idx+1] && newpartitions[idx+1]-newpartitions[idx]>=1)
            {
                partitions[tmp]=newpartitions[idx];
                partitions[tmp+1]=newpartitions[idx+1];
                tmp+=2;
            }
        }
        threads=tmp/2;

        if (threads==0)
            break;
    } // end main loop

    cudaMemcpy(c,dev_c, count* sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_p);
    cudaFree(dev_pn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i tried style of definition below instead of "int partitions[1024];".
//test has 10 elements.(you need to change 10 to 1024) then it set all values to 0.

```
unsigned int *test;
test=(unsigned int*) malloc(10*sizeof(unsigned int));
test=new unsigned int[10];
for(int w=0;w<10;w++)
    test[w]=0;
```